# Elasticsearch query for nested field existence

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document saved in the Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "transactionGroup": [
    {
      "name": "Test123",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Grp1",
          "groups": [
            {
              "name": "g1",
              "groups": [
                {
                  "name": "g11",
                  "columns": {
                    "cpm": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    },
                    "imps": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "g12",
                  "columns": {
                    "cpm": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    },
                    "imps": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "columns": {
                "period": {
                  "newValue": "3Q"
                },
                "channelid": {
                  "newValue": "rQ"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "g2",
              "groups": [
                {
                  "name": "g21",
                  "columns": {
                    "cpm": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    },
                    "imps": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "g22",
                  "columns": {
                    "cpm": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    },
                    "imps": {
                      "newValue": "0"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "columns": {
                "period": {
                  "newValue": "3Q"
                },
                "channelid": {
                  "newValue": "rQ"
                }
              }
            }            
          ],
          "columns": {
            "entityid": {
              "newValue": "3292"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "columns": {
        "lastmodifieddate": {
          "newValue": "2020-05-18 07:29:54"
        },
        "lastmodifiedby": {
          "newValue": "ajay"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want following query.

How can I execute an `exists` query for:

`If a group having name="g1", nested name="g11" having column field "cpm.newvalue" ?`

I was trying something like:

```
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "*transactionGroup.groups.groups.groups.columns.cpm.newValue",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
```

But it's not working in all cases.

Here is the mapping:

```
{"unifiedplanner":{"_all":{"enabled":true,"norms":false},"properties":{"transactionGroup":{"properties":{"columns":{"properties":{"calendarid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"channel":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"class":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createdby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"dealyearid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"demo":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"enddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"endperiodid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"entityid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"equivalised":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"exceptions":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"exclusivity":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"fluidity":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"guaranteed":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"hiatus":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifiedby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifieddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"oldValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"marketplaceid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"maxlineid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"ordertypeid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"periodbreakdown":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"planclassid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"planid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"planname":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"plannotes":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"platform":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"ratecard":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"ratingstreamid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"startdate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"startperiodid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"type":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"version":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}}}},"groups":{"properties":{"columns":{"properties":{"$oid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"address":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"asofdate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"brandid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"categoryid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"channelid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"commission":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"contactid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"corporate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createdby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"daysofweek":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"demo":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"divisionid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"downstreamplanstatusid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"enddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"endtime":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"entityid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"externalid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"extsourceid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"gender":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"guaranteedcalculated":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"id":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifiedby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifieddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"mode":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"name":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"notes":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"optionabledollartotal":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"optionablepercenttotal":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"optiondata":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"planhasnooptions":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"primary":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"revision":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"role":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"roles":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"seccategoryid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"secondary":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"self":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"separationtype":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"split":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"startdate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"starttime":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"statusid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"oldValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"statusname":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"oldValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"subdivisionid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"subjecttooptiontotal":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"teamid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"title":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"username":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"version":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}}}},"groups":{"properties":{"columns":{"properties":{"$oid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"channelid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"channelname":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"class":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"cpm":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createdby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"createddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"daysinadvance":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"daysofweek":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"dollar":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"externalid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"externalsourcesystems":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"extsourceid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"id":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"imps":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifiedby":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"lastmodifieddate":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"oldValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"name":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"optionabledollar":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"optionablepercent":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"period":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"planclass":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"platform":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"programid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"statusid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"statusname":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"subjecttooption":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}}}},"groups":{"properties":{"columns":{"properties":{"$oid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"cpm":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"dollar":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"externalid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"extsourceid":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"id":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"imps":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}},"name":{"properties":{"newValue":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"long"}}}}},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"transactionSummary":{"properties":{"auditID":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"binLogTransactionId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"databaseType":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"modifiedTime":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"moduleName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"moduleTransactionId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"rootEntityID":{"type":"keyword"},"schema":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"source":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"sourceTstamp":{"type":"long"},"userFullName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"userName":{"type":"keyword"}}}}},"_default_":{"_all":{"enabled":true,"norms":false},"properties":{"transactionSummary":{"properties":{"rootEntityID":{"type":"keyword"},"userName":{"type":"keyword"}}}}}}
```

Comment: can you add your mapping?

Comment: i updated the mapping details

Comment: JSON mentioned in question might be slightly different

Comment: In your mapping, all properties have object type(flat structered), none of these have nested type. Do you want to include a document if any object in array has field or yu want to also match an object in array on other fields ex object should have name="g1", nested name="g11"

Comment: I want two type of query: 1. find the `cpm` data if exist for `grp1 -> g1 -> g11 -> columns -> cpm -> newvalue/oldvalue` 2. find the data if exist for `grp1-> columns -> period ->newvalue/oldvalue

Comment: You need to create array with type 'nested" and use nested query

Comment: can you pls give one example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214147/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-manish-kumar).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have a `*` in here? `"field" : "*tran...` I would like to warn you that wildcards are not supported in `exists` query.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to decide which type to assign to your field [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) or [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

**Example** If you have an array with first names and last names

```
"users:[
        {
         "firstName":"a",
         "lastName":"b" 
        },
        {
         "firstName":"x",
         "lastName":"y" 
        }
]
```

In object type relationship between fields of array doesn't exist.
Suppose if you search for user whose firstName is "a" and last name "y". With object type above document will be returned (even though no such user exists) as objects are not treated as separate documents , you need to use nested type which is less performant than object.

If you decide to make our arrays as nested type, you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to search on them

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "groups",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "groups.name": {
                      "value": "grp1"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "groups.groups",
                    "query": {
                      "exists": {
                       "field": "groups.groups.field1"--> full name needed(full heirerchy)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```